# GORM hasMany using multiple columns

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a class as follows

```
class PrefValue extends MainDomain {

    String entityClass
    Long entityId
    ....
}
```

I am now trying to map a collection to two different classes

```
class TypeA extends MainDomain {
  Long entityId
  static hasMany = [preferences:PrefValue]
  static mappedBy = [preferences: "entityId"]
  ...
}
class TypeB extends MainDomain {
  Long entityId
  static hasMany = [preferences:PrefValue]
  static mappedBy = [preferences: "entityId"]
}
```

The problem arises because both TypeA and TypeB can have the same ID but they will have different entityClass values. How would I map this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `entityId` is the primary key, leading to issues when `TypeA` and `TypeB` both have the same value for their primary key.

In this case you can drop the primary key constraint and instead use a composite primary key instead.  The documentation goes into more detail about it [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#compositePrimaryKeys).

If you it is NOT a primary key and is just has a unique constraint, then you can make the `entityId` unique per discriminator:

`static mapping = {
    entityId unique: 'entityClass'
}`

Comment: So you are right about entityId but entityClass is the class name in string form (TypeA TypeB). So will this still work? Will it effect persistence?

Comment: @Jackie Yeah I believe the way unique works is by checking that the value is unique given the other column's value.  I'm not sure why it would affect persistence.  If validation fails, then GORM won't persist it, but are you asking about something else?  You can always write some integration tests to check this.

Comment: Ahh I see it wasn't clear at first that you were talking about the Id on the "PrefValue" class. I get that now and I will try some stuff out tomorrow. I just wonder how I let it know that the combo I want is the one with "X" entityClass. I think this might work because the entity ID isn't unique when it comes to that class, only TypeA and TypeB use it as an ID. Thanks! (won't let me @ you for some reason)